# Returning arrays strategy comparison

Tags: fortran, fortran90

In Fortran, I can return arrays from a subroutine with three approaches. The first one is via an `intent(out)` parameter. The second one is via a function having the array as `result`. The third one is to have a function having as `result` a pointer to array, which is allocated in the function.

What are the advantages and disadvantages of each approach ?

Answer (score 5):

My practice is to use a function return when the function alters only one variable and makes no other output.   If multiple variables are changed or the procedure performs other actions I would place the output variables in the argument list.   This is a style choice.   It is possible to create memory leaks with pointers, especially with pointers returned as function arguments, so I would avoid this option unless there was a compelling reason in the particular case.

UPDATE: There is no problem with an intent (out) array argument ... no assumptions need be made about the size of the array, as the following example shows:

```
module example_one

implicit none

contains

subroutine two_arrays ( in_arr, out_arr )

   integer, dimension (:), intent (in) :: in_arr
   integer, dimension (:), allocatable, intent (out) :: out_arr

   integer :: i, len

   len = size (in_arr)

   allocate ( out_arr (1:len) )

   do i=1, len
      out_arr (i) = 3 * in_arr (i)
   end do

return

end subroutine two_arrays

end module example_one


program test

use example_one

implicit none

integer, dimension (1:5)  :: in_arr = [ 1, 2, 4, 5, 10 ]
integer, dimension (:), allocatable :: out_arr

write (*, *) allocated ( out_arr)
call two_arrays ( in_arr, out_arr )

write (*, *) size (out_arr)
write (*, *) out_arr

write (*, *) allocated ( out_arr)
deallocate ( out_arr )
write (*, *) allocated ( out_arr)

stop

end program test
```

Comment: are there problems such as stack crashes when you return with the different strategies ? suppose you return an array of 1 million reals. will you overflow the stack, and will it be copied from the function context to the caller context ?

Answer (score 0):

1. `intent(out)` can be a problem as you have to make assumptions about the size of the array being passed in.
2. returning an array is also a problem as the receiving code will have to make assumptions about the size of the array being returned
3. pointers to arrays have the problems related to size plus the problem of making assumptions about whether the pointer is associated or not.
4. the alternative is to create a module, and in that module have a type which contains both an allocatable array and an integer detailing the size of the array:

```
module mymodule
    type myvector
        double precision,allocatable::values(:)
        integer::length
    end type
end module
```

Then your function can be:

```
function myvecreturner(someparam)
    use mymodule
    type(myvector)::myvecreturner
    integer::someparam

    allocate(myvecreturner%values(someparam))
    myvecreturner%length = someparam
end function
```

And you can pass these myvector types around happily. Just remember to deallocate the arrays when you're done with them...

Comment: Well, technically, you already carry around the size of an array, without the need for a type. inquiring with `size` achieves the same effect.

Comment: There are also solutions to #2.  Functions can return allocatable arrays.   See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647772/function-returning-array-with-no-defined-explicit-shape